# Streaming facebook data into Hadoop HDFS

Tags: facebook, hadoop, streaming, flume

I want to analyse Social media data with Hadoop. I used flume to stream Twitter data into hadoop using custom source but for Facebook I didn't find anything for streaming though I can use API for downloading the FB data.

Is it possible using any other tool than flume? Can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

There are no public streaming endpoints in the Graph API, unlike with Twitter. Theonly thing I imagine you could use are the Realtime Updates, but therefore you's either need a Facebook app or a facebook Page which you could subscribe to.